# How to put variable value inside another variable name in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am pretty new to Swift and I want to make a pretty big list of images called image1, image2, image3 and so on. The problem is that I need to make something like this:

var index = 1
...
image(index).image = ...
index+=1

where index is a counter for my images ( image(index) to be image1, for example)
but I don't know the right syntax for image(index).

Can someone let me know how?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on Arrays?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
let imageArray = [UIImage]()

for i in 0..<limit {
    imageArray.append(UIImage(named: "image\(i)"))
}
```

Comment: But it says "Expected declaration" on the line with for... Do you know why?

Comment: you have to write the number on images instead of limit

Answer (score 0):

If you want to init the image by name, image1jpg image2.jpg... image53.jpg you should do this:

`let imageName = "image\(index).jpg"`

Then just create the image with the name

Comment: Thanks. I will try that too

Answer (score 0):

I guess you only need an array …

```
var images = [String]()
images.append("image1.jpg")
images.append("image2.jpg")
print(images.first) // "image1.jpg"
print(images[1]) // "image2.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially you need drag drop your all images into your Xcode project file with naming convention like image_1.png, image_2.png .... image_50.png

```
and write the code on your view controller

let imageArray:String = [String]()

for index in 1..<51 {
 imageArray.append(UIImage(named: "image_\(index)"))
 }

now you will get the an array of images name that reflect your stored images.
```

Comment: I have the images connected to the view controller but I don't know about what declaration is talking about

Comment: In that case create an outlet with the imageView. Be clear while posting the question.